# gmail oauth imap zend retrieve from gmail instead of session

Tags: zend-framework, oauth, gmail, imap

Im planning to use google oauth IMAP to sign up for my website.
Im using zend framework for the same.
http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-xoauth-tools/wiki/PhpSampleCode
Also im suing 3 legged approach to sign up 
When i go through the sample threelegged.php.
I find that i t has email address inbox and he keeps it in a session and goes to access the gmail account and once he returns back he retireves the email id from the session

$email_address = $_SESSION['email_address'];

Line No.121

$config = new Zend_Oauth_Config();

$config->setOptions($options);

$config->setToken($accessToken);

$config->setRequestMethod('GET');

$url = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/b/' .
       $email_address . 
       '/imap/';

My requirement is i do not want to have email address to be kept in session instead i want the given the gmail address to be retrieved in 
$email address.
How can i do that ?
Is any function supporting it  in Zend framework?

Answer (score 0):

http://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/Home/emaildisplayscope

You will need to include the authorization url with your other urls you are asking permission to get data from:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

Then when you actually get the authorized token you can do it like this:

```
// Get access token from session after authorization process is complete.
$accessToken = unserialize($_SESSION['ACCESS_TOKEN']);

// Retrieve email address using Access Token
$erequest = $accessToken->getHttpClient($options);
$erequest->setUri('https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/email');
$erequest->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::GET);
$ereturn = $erequest->request();
parse_str($ereturn->getBody(), $earray);
$email_address = $earray['email'];

// Retrieve mail using Access Token
$config = new Zend_Oauth_Config();
$config->setOptions($options);
$config->setToken($accessToken);
$config->setRequestMethod('GET');
$url = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/b/' .
   $email_address . 
   '/imap/';
```

This is after authenticating a token for accessing the data.  Then the email address can be used for your mail request or anything else that requires the email address.